# Asking for the idomatic way respectively for avoiding a duplicate in the code

Tags: common-lisp

(Just for fun) I figured out a way to represent this:

```
250 : 8 = 31 + 2
 31 : 8 = 3 + 7
∴ (372)8
```

in the following procedure:

```
(defun dec->opns (n base)
   (do* ((lst nil (append lst (list pos))) ; this is also not so nice
         (m n (truncate m base))
         (pos (rem m base) (rem m base)) ) ; <<<<<<
        ((< m base) (reverse (append lst (list m)))) ))
```

The procedure does what it is supposed to do until now.

```
 CL-USER> (dec->opns 2500000 8)
 (1 1 4 2 2 6 4 0)
```

At this point, I simply ask myself, how to avoid the two times

`(rem m base)`.

First of all because of duplicates are looking daft. But also they may be a hint that the solution isn't the elegant way. Which also is not a problem. I am studying for becoming a primary school teacher (from 1st to 6nd class) and am considering examples for exploring math in a sense of Paperts Mindstorms. Therefore exploring all stages of creating and refining a solution are welcome.

But to get a glimpse of the professional solution, would you be so kind to suggest a more elegant way to implement the algorithm in an idiomatic way?

(Just to anticipate opposition to my "plan": I have no intentions to overwhelm the youngsters with Common Lisp. For now, I am using Common Lisp for reflecting about my study content and using the student content for practicing Common Lisp. My intention in the medium term is to write a "common (lisp) Logo setup" and a Logo environment with which the examples in Harveys Computer Science Logo style (vol. 1), Paperts Mindstorms, Solomons et. al LogoWorks, and of course in Abelsons et. al Turtle Geometry can be implemented uncompromisingly. If I will not cave in, the library will be found with quickload in the still more distant future under the name "c-logo-s" and be called *cλogos* ;-) )

Comment: Sorry - what `dec->opns` should actually do? In human words?

Comment: I don't get the `∴ (372)8` what this has to do with the modulo expressions above it ...

Comment: It transforms a decimal number into another positional notation system.

Comment: looks like this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19892507/how-do-i-convert-a-decimal-number-to-a-list-of-octal-digits-in-common-lisp

Comment: The last quotient is 3 * 8² and the remainders are 7 * 8² and 2 * 8⁰.

Comment: and this https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Non-decimal_radices/Convert#Common_Lisp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### The closest to your code

You can reduce the reversing of the reversing and append -> by using `cons` only. The duplication of `(rem m base)` is only an optical issue, since the first `(rem m base)` gets executed only the first time the loop runs and the second `(rem m base)` in all other cases. Thus they are actually not a duplication. One cannot use a `let` here, because of the required syntax within the macro. `(<variable> <initial-value> <progression-for-each-round>)`

```
(defun dec->ops (n base)
  (do* ((acc nil (cons r acc))
        (m n (truncate m base))
        (r (rem m base) (rem m base)))
       ((zerop m) acc)))
```

#### The most Common Lispy version

The rosetta solutions for Common Lisp seems to give the most Common Lisp-like ways - either using `write-to-string`/`parse-integer` or even some `format` quircks.

```
(defun decimal->base-n (n base)
  (write-to-string n :base base))
(defun base-n->decimal (base-n base)
  (parse-integer (format nil "~a" base-n) :radix base))
```

```
(defun decimal-to-base-n (number &key (base 16))
  (format nil (format nil "~~~dr" base) number))

(defun base-n-to-decimal (number &key (base 16))
  (read-from-string (format nil "#~dr~d" base number)))

;; or:

(defun change-base (number input-base output-base)
  (format nil "~vr" output-base (parse-integer number :radix input-base)))
```

Source: https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Non-decimal_radices/Convert#Common_Lisp

```
(decimal-to-base-n 2500000 :base 8)
;;=> "11422640"
```

#### Solution without `format` or `write-to-string`/`parse-integer`

Use tail call recursion:

```
(defun dec->ops (n base &optional (acc nil))
  (if (< n base) 
      (cons n acc)
      (multiple-value-bind (m r) (truncate n base)
        (dec->ops m base (cons r acc)))))
```

Try it:

```
[41]> (dec->ops 250 8)
(3 7 2)
[42]> (dec->ops 250000 8)
(7 5 0 2 2 0)
[43]> (dec->ops 2500000 8)
(1 1 4 2 2 6 4 0)
```

The `do/do*` macros are in this case not so nice, because one cannot capture the multiple values returned by `truncate` nicely (`truncate` is `mod` and `rem` in one function - one should use this fact).

#### If you really wants to use `do*`

```
(defun dec->ops (n base)
  (do* ((acc nil (cons (second values) acc))
        (values (list n) (multiple-value-list (truncate (first values) base))))
       ((< (first values) base) (nbutlast (cons (first values) (cons (second values) acc))))))
```

This works

```
[69]> (dec->ops 250 8)
(3 7 2)
[70]> (dec->ops 2500000 8)
(1 1 4 2 2 6 4 0)
```

Comment: Thank you very much :-) I wanted to avoid FORMAT for explicitly translating the calculation path into a procedure thus pretending that FORMAT does not exist. Instead I have chosen the DO macro also to avoid a recursive solution simply to trust the more efficient built in iteration. Yet I have to admit, that it looks much more pretty. So, I will consider it gratefully.

Comment: Ah okay - so something recursive. I can tell you from your code - instead of `append` you `cons` in Lisp - but that of course adds only at the start and not at the end. So you `nreverse` the result - `nreverse` is mutating - but it doesn't matter - because you the `cons`-ed list is anyway garbage collected when returned as result. - to your duplicated `(rem m base)` - you use `let` to calculated it just once.

Comment: actually `(rem m base)` is even superfluous,because `(truncate n base)` already returns modulo and its reminder. You have to use `multiple-value-bind` to catch it!

Comment: `(multiple-value-bind (m r) (truncate 31 8) (list m r))` e.g. returns: `(3 7)`

Comment: but one cannoto use `multiple-value-bind` within `do` construct - one should better use `loop` because it destructures. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41628381/mutiple-value-bind-in-do-loop-in-common-lisp

Comment: But I realize that the usual `cons`-`nreverse` idiom is not needed here, because one doesn't need to reverse in this special case.

Comment: First I thought of `multiple-value-bind`, then I saw `multiple-value-list`, the shorthand for your example yet this somehow didn't fit into my idea at that stage. But it's good to know, that this doesn't work in `do` anyway. While I was writing this I also thought of first move to `loop` before trying the recursive way.
`cons`ing is more efficient, right? I now wonder why I chose this way. Something didn't work out the way I used `cons` before. 
However, thank you very much for your hints!

Comment: Yes, not so easy. I added a `do*` version. One has however to use several tricks ... `butlast` to remove the first attachment etc ... not THAT elegant. - one could use the destructive `nbutlast` to improve it performance-wise ...

Comment: Added finally at the very beginning - the most closest-to-your-code version.

Answer (score 2):

I would go with the following implementation when trying to avoid recursion:

```
(defun digits-in-base (number base)
  (check-type number (integer 0))
  (check-type base (integer 2))
  (loop
    :with remainder
    :do (multiple-value-setq (number remainder) (truncate number base))
    :collect remainder
    :until (= number 0)))
```

Multiple values are not directly handled by `LOOP` so instead of converting the values to a list I prefer using `MULTIPLE-VALUE-SETQ` to update multiple values at once.

The code first does some type checks because otherwise it can loop infinitely: the inputs are expected to be respectively positive or null, and greater than 1.

I put the `:until` condition at the end so that `0` gives `(0)`.

Note that the digits are sorted from the smallest to the highest rank:

```
(digits-in-base 4 2)
=> (0 0 1)

(digits-in-base 250 8)
=> (2 7 3)
```

Alternatively, for the reverse order:

```
(defun digits-in-base (number base)
  (check-type number (integer 0))
  (check-type base (integer 2))
  (loop
    :with remainder :and digits
    :do (multiple-value-setq (number remainder) (truncate number base))
    :do (push remainder digits)
    :until (= number 0)
    :finally (return digits)))

(digits-in-base 4 2)
=> (1 0 0)

(digits-in-base 250 8)
=> (3 7 2)
```

In a previous version of this answer I said the first one (from low to high digits) is better for further manipulation of the digits, but I am not so sure.

Converting back to  a number is quite easy with number arranged from high to low digits (all the code below use the second version):

```
(defun digits-to-number (digits base)
  (reduce (lambda (n d) (+ d (* n base)))
          digits
          :initial-value 0))
```

So is formatting to a string:

```
(defun number-string-base (number base)
  (format nil
          (if (<= base 10)
              "(~{~d~})~d"
            "(~{~d~^'~})~d")
          (digits-in-base number base)
          base))

(number-string-base 250 8)
=> "(372)8"

(number-string-base 250 16)
=> "(15'10)16"
```

Comment: Or for reverse order, just put `(nreverse ..)` around the first `loop` which contains `:collect remainder`.

Comment: But thanks for the nice answer - as always quite an insightfull answer. I learned more about the `loop` macro syntax. And the trick to let the loop run through until `number` gets zero is quite useful for simplification of the code.

Comment: Again. Thank you so very much. Now I have a lot to comprehend and reproduce. Perfect!

Answer (score 0):

Since you expressed interest in various approaches, one thing worth remembering is that Lisp's great strength is *creating and extending languages*.  Indeed all the iteration constructs in Common Lisp are such extensions: CL has no primitive iteration constructs at all.

So there is nothing preventing anyone writing their own, which will be just as good as the ones the language provides.  For instance Tim Bradshaw's [simple loops](https://tfeb.github.io/tfeb-lisp-hax/#decomposing-iteration-simple-loops) provides an 'applicative looping construct', `looping`, which makes this quite simple to implement:

```
(defun dec->ops (n base)
  (looping ((m n)
            (a '()))
    (when (< (abs m) base)
      (return (cons m a)))
    (multiple-value-bind (q r) (truncate m base)
      (values q (cons r a)))))
```

Using `looping`, the variables bound in the loop are updated by the values of the last form in the loop's body.

Of course this is rather close to the classic tail-recursive implementation (here using [iterate](https://tfeb.github.io/tfeb-lisp-hax/#applicative-iteration-iterate)):

```
(defun dec->ops (n base)
  (iterate next ((m n)
                 (a '()))
    (if (< (abs m) base)
        (cons m a)
      (multiple-value-bind (q r) (truncate m base)
        (next q (cons r a))))))
```

People tend not to like things like this because they are 'not idiomatic CL' of course.